# Using Ubuntu alone as an OS

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, default

As subjected, I am looking to use Ubuntu as an ONLY OS for my Laptop. I was using Windows 7 & Windows 8 [Not-Activated]. Then I thought to use Ubuntu only, and to just un-install both the OSs from this laptop. I tried installing Ubuntu, but in result it formatted my whole Hard Drive, deleted all 4 partitions, and made a Single Partition. So did I lost all my personal stuff as well. Now, after a bit of hard work, I restored and recovered my partitions and data back in state. Now, I have a 100GB FREE partition at "C", rest D, E & F are fully occupied with my personal stuff. Now, I have a Bootable USB ready with me with Ubuntu 14 and looking to Install this on C only, without affecting my personal stuff. please guide me through the way for it. Om installation pane I see two options, Erase Disk & Something Else. After moving onto Something Else, I am confused to select the options from partitioning table. Please guide me through.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain as to what you are asking, but dual booting Windows and Ubuntu, as well as just having Ubuntu as your single OS, is very doable.

[Here is an in-depth guide on how to install Ubuntu 14.04.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

You can initially try Ubuntu by running it off a CD/USB key. Clicking "Install Ubuntu 14.04" will guide through through the process. You will hit an "Installation Type" screen as seen below.

[image]

If you plan on Ubuntu as your *only* operating system, you should go ahead and click "Replace Windows X with Ubuntu".

If you want to dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu, I suggest clicking "Something Else", which will allow you to properly partition your hard drive. Both Windows and Ubuntu should be in separate partitions. You can resize the partitions however you like, as long as they are sufficiently large.